# convert php response array as comma separated

Tags: php

I am trying to get facebook friends by using facebook api.

I am getting response

```
   {
  "data": [
  {
     "id": "groupID",
     "members": {
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "Abc",
              "administrator": false,
              "id": "xxxxxx"
           },
           {
              "name": "NewCas",
              "administrator": false,
              "id": "xxxxxxxxx"
           },
           {
              "name": "Cds",
              "administrator": false,
              "id": "xxxxxxxxx"
           },
           {
              "name": "akaha",
              "administrator": false,
              "id": "xxxxxxx"
           },

  }

}
```

This is my code

```
$fql = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?fields=id,members&access_token='.$access_token.'&limit=3';
$fqlresult = file_get_contents($fql); 
$f = json_decode($fqlresult, true);
```

tried implode.

```
$result = implode(',', array_column($f['data'], 'id'));
```

I am getting this response

```
GroupID,GroupID,GroupID
```

I want to take response user ids (members id) as

```
xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx
```

Thanks

Comment: could you post the part where you did try to implode the response?

Comment: `$result = implode(',', array_column($response['data'], 'id'));`

Comment: $mystring = implode("," , $f1);

Comment: try this: `echo implode(", ", array_column($arr['data'], 'id'))`

Comment: hello sir I changed my code for group members .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are almost correct, but the `data` is an array with one element so it should be:

```
echo implode(',', array_column($f['data'][0]['members']['data'], 'id'));
```

and that is when you have only one groupid, if you have multiple group ids you will need to loop trough it. (loop over the `[0]` by checking `$groupcount = count($f['data']);`

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
$arr = array(
    'data' => array(
        array('id' => 'xxxx1'),
        array('id' => 'xxxx2'),
        array('id' => 'xxxx3'),
        array('id' => 'xxxx4'),
        array('id' => 'xxxx5'),
        array('id' => 'xxxx6'),
        array('id' => 'xxxx7'),
        array('id' => 'xxxx8'),
    )
);

echo implode(',', array_column($arr['data'], 'id'));
```

EDIT - based on your update and change of request...

```
echo implode(',', array_column($arr['data'][0]['members']['data'], 'id'));
```

please review http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and the section on multidimensional arrays

Comment: Hello sir I just changed my code a bit for getting group members.

Comment: well I didn't test it the same way as I don't have the exact object setup, but there was some independent thought assumed on your part by reading and understanding multi dimensional arrays.  I'll make one final edit and then if it works, I'd appreciate this being selected, otherwise I'll leave this question as I normally only 3 changes on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo implode(',', array_column($f['data'][0]['members']['data'], 'id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_arr=json_decode($data,true);
$return_str="";
foreach($data_arr['data'] as $row)
{
    $return_str .=implode(", ", array_column($row['members']['data'], 'id'))  ;  
}
echo rtrim($return_str,",");
```

This will work for multiple elements in $f['data'].

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PHP version is 5.5+. Below the specified version will not support array_column function. You can also use this code without array_column.

```
$data = $result['data'][0]['members']['data'];
$keyValue = '';

foreach ($data as $outerKey => $outerValue) {
  foreach ($outerValue as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'id'){
      $keyValue .= $value . ' ';
    }
  }
}
echo $keyValue;
```